# Dual boot (Win10 & Mint) "storage drive": rw mount /etc/fstab loads as read-only

Tags: dual-boot, fstab, ntfs

Im following along [howtogeek: how to harmonize your dual boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/), however I have ran in to an issue. I have added my storage drive to `etc/fstab` as followed:

```
# storage mount
UUID=748A56588A5616C8 /media/storage/    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0
```

based on my result from `blkid`

```
sudo blkid | grep Storage
/dev/nvme0n1p7: LABEL="Storage" UUID="748A56588A5616C8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="17c911ed-1b6b-4d69-a08a-f5aec2e74439"
```

The issue is that when I reboot, my drive is there but mounted in as read-only mode

[image]

Comment: If you are hibernating for example, that is normal. But otherwise Windows 10 might not actually "release" the drive in a _fast startup_ reboot/shutdown (the default), so in Windows try clicking on reboot/shutdown while pressing Shift. Does it solve it?

Comment: Interesting, pressing down `shift` does solve the issue. Is this something I'll have to do everytime or could this "release" mechanic be invoked automatically (with regular shutdown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 10 by default does a *fast startup* that does not fully release the drives in use. Linux cannot then write to them, because that would lead to corruption.

A temporary solution is to press Shift as you restart/reboot Windows 10. But that should be repeated every time.

A more permanent solution can be found [here](https://lifehacker.com/shutting-down-windows-10-doesnt-actually-shut-down-wind-1825532376). I do not quote the details of those steps because it feels off-topic.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for the clarification. I wish you a fine day!